# How can I test a Robospice GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest? Currently getting NullPointerException for HttpRequestFactory

Tags: android, testing, robospice

I'm trying to test my class *CachedGetRequest* which extends from *GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest*.

Following the example [here](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Testing-a-RoboSpice-request) I have written this test:

```
@LargeTest
public class CachedGetRequestTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    private MockWebServer mServer;
    private CachedGetRequest<Product> mCachedGetRequest;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        mServer = new MockWebServer();
        mServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(...));
        mServer.start();
        URL url = mServer.getUrl("/api/products/");

        mCachedGetRequest = new CachedGetRequest<>(Product.class, url.toString(), "", "");
    }

    public void testLoadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        Product product = mCachedGetRequest.loadDataFromNetwork();
        assertTrue(product.getName().equals("Test"));
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(java.lang.String, com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl, com.google.api.client.http.HttpContent)' on a null object reference
```

If I try using a simple request like the *SimpleTextRequest* used in the example, then it works just fine. So it works for a basic *SpiceRequest* but not for a *GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest*.

I see that the *HttpRequestFactory* is null but how can I set it? I can call *setHttpRequestFactory* on the request but I cannot mock a *HttpRequestFactory* with Mockito as it's a final class. How can I correctly test this Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [wiki page for testing RoboSpice requests](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Testing-a-RoboSpice-request) (second example). It should address your problem after a simple adaptation:

```
...
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    // ...
    // your setup code, as specified in the question
    // ...

    mCachedGetRequest.setHttpRequestFactory(GoogleHttpClientSpiceService.createRequestFactory());
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought I had to mock the HttpRequestFactory but your example works perfectly.